# Вопрос по конструкции (Subprocess, thread)

Tags: python, многопоточность, api

Скажите, пожалуйста, что из библиотек использовать?
Задача в описании кода.
orbit - это функция, которая вытаскивает несколько списков.

```
for zond in orbit:
    try.scan()
    try.scan()
    try.scan()
    if float(scan) > 1:
        process()# Нужно выполнить в отдельном потоке, а сам цикл продолжил работу,
                 # запуская каждый proccess(), если scan() показал больше 1.
    else:
        continue
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы процессы из итераций пошли отдельным потоком?
Thread или subprocess? Читал описание и того и другого. Не очень понял, что subprocess делает.

Comment: А результат этого `process` вас интересует? И что там запускается - что-то питоновское или нет? От этого будет зависеть какое решение лучше использовать.

Comment: Да. Там будут импортироваться другие py. Происходить расчеты и вычисления. Вплоть до обращения к API.

Comment: Если там тоже питон, то лучше `thread`, а `subprocess` нужен, если вы хотите операционку попросить что-то запустить произвольное, не обязательно питоновское. Это более тяжеловесно получается и нельзя толком контролировать из питона. А с `thread` вы можете "общаться", влиять на него (например, легко его остановить).

Comment: Спасибо, буду `thread` изучать

Answer (score -1):

```
for zond in orbit:
    try.scan()
    try.scan()
    try.scan()
    if float(scan) > 1:
        t1 = Thread(target = process)
        t1.start()
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: process без скобок должен быть: `t1 = Thread(target = process)`, иначе он сразу запустится, а не в отдельном потоке. Еще не понятно что за конструкция `try.scan()` - try - это ключевое слово, попытка вызвать от него какой-то метод вызовет ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: try это сторонняя библиотека. scan - функция  в ней.

Comment: Значит у вас какой-то "нестандартный" Python. В обычном Python нельзя назвать переменную, модуль, функцию, класс, объект и т.д. как try, потому что это ключевое слово языка, использующееся в конструкции try-except